# Tic-Tac-Toe checking not working as I want it to at the end of my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to make this Tic-tac-toe game and in the last part of my code it's suppose check if the number in circleList however the only check that works as intended is 1,4,7. Becuse when I press the boxes 3,6,7,8,9 the line shows up right away I don't know why

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 840))
wn.fill((8, 140, 120))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tic-Tac-Toe")
First = pygame.draw.rect(wn, (20, 189, 172), (10, 210, 200,200))
Second = pygame.draw.rect(wn, (20, 189, 172), (220, 210, 200,200))
Third = pygame.draw.rect(wn, (20, 189, 172), (430, 210, 200,200))
Fourth = pygame.draw.rect(wn, (20, 189, 172), (10, 420, 200,200))
Fifth = pygame.draw.rect(wn, (20, 189, 172), (220, 420, 200,200))
Sixth = pygame.draw.rect(wn, (20, 189, 172), (430, 420, 200,200))
Seventh = pygame.draw.rect(wn, (20, 189, 172), (10,630, 200,200))
Eight = pygame.draw.rect(wn, (20, 189, 172), (220, 630, 200,200))
Ninth = pygame.draw.rect(wn, (20, 189, 172), (430, 630, 200,200))
Circle = False

Flag = True
First_Empty = True
Second_Empty = True
Third_Empty = True
Fourth_Empty = True
Fifth_Empty = True
Sixth_Empty = True
Seventh_Empty = True
Eight_Empty = True
Ninth_Empty = True

circleList = []
xList = []


while Flag:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Flag = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            if First.collidepoint(pos) and First_Empty:
                if Circle:
                    pygame.draw.circle(wn,(8, 140, 120), (110, 310), 90, 20)
                    circleList.append(1)
                    Circle = False
                    First_Empty = False
                else:
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (40,230), (180,380),20)
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (180, 230), (40, 380), 20)
                    xList.append(1)
                    Circle = True
                    First_Empty = False

            if Second.collidepoint(pos) and Second_Empty:
                if Circle:
                    pygame.draw.circle(wn,(8, 140, 120), (320, 310), 90, 20)
                    circleList.append(2)
                    Circle = False
                    Second_Empty = False
                else:
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (250,230), (380,380),20)
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (380, 230), (250, 380), 20)
                    xList.append(2)
                    Circle = True
                    Second_Empty = False

            if Third.collidepoint(pos) and Third_Empty:
                if Circle:
                    pygame.draw.circle(wn,(8, 140, 120), (530, 310), 90, 20)
                    circleList.append(3)
                    Circle = False
                    Third_Empty = False
                else:
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (450,230), (600, 380), 20)
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (600, 230), (450, 380), 20)
                    xList.append(3)
                    Circle = True
                    Third_Empty = False

            if Fourth.collidepoint(pos) and Fourth_Empty:
                if Circle:
                    pygame.draw.circle(wn,(8, 140, 120), (110, 520), 90, 20)
                    Circle = False
                    circleList.append(4)
                    Fourth_Empty = False
                else:
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (40,440), (180,580),20)
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (180, 440), (40, 580), 20)
                    xList.append(4)
                    Circle = True
                    Fourth_Empty = False

            if Fifth.collidepoint(pos) and Fifth_Empty:
                if Circle:
                    pygame.draw.circle(wn,(8, 140, 120), (320, 520), 90, 20)
                    Circle = False
                    circleList.append(5)
                    Fifth_Empty = False
                else:
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (250,440), (380,590),20)
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (380, 440), (250, 590), 20)
                    xList.append(5)
                    Circle = True
                    Fifth_Empty = False

            if Sixth.collidepoint(pos) and Sixth_Empty:
                if Circle:
                    pygame.draw.circle(wn, (8, 140, 120), (530, 520), 90, 20)
                    Circle = False
                    circleList.append(6)
                    Sixth_Empty = False
                else:
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (450, 440), (600, 590), 20)
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (600, 440), (450, 590), 20)
                    xList.append(6)
                    Circle = True
                    Sixth_Empty = False

            if Seventh.collidepoint(pos) and Seventh_Empty:
                if Circle:
                    pygame.draw.circle(wn,(8, 140, 120), (110, 730), 90, 20)
                    Circle = False
                    circleList.append(7)
                    Seventh_Empty = False
                else:
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (40,650), (180,800),20)
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (180, 650), (40, 800), 20)
                    xList.append(7)
                    Circle = True
                    Seventh_Empty = False

            if Eight.collidepoint(pos) and Eight_Empty:
                if Circle:
                    pygame.draw.circle(wn,(8, 140, 120), (320, 730), 90, 20)
                    Circle = False
                    circleList.append(8)
                    Eight_Empty = False
                else:
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (250,650), (380,800),20)
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (380, 650), (250, 800), 20)
                    xList.append(8)
                    Circle = True
                    Eight_Empty = False

            if Ninth.collidepoint(pos) and Ninth_Empty:
                if Circle:
                    pygame.draw.circle(wn, (8, 140, 120), (530, 730), 90, 20)
                    Circle = False
                    circleList.append(9)
                    Ninth_Empty = False
                else:
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (450, 650), (600, 800), 20)
                    pygame.draw.line(wn, (8, 140, 120), (600, 650), (450, 800), 20)
                    xList.append(9)
                    Circle = True
                    Ninth_Empty = False

            if 1 and 2 and 3 in circleList:
                pygame.draw.line(wn, (208, 240, 192), (10, 305), (630, 305), 20)
            elif 1 and 5 and 9 in circleList:
                pygame.draw.line(wn, (208,240,192), (10, 305), (630, 305), 20)
            elif 1 and 4 and 7 in circleList:
                pygame.draw.line(wn, (208,240,192), (10, 305), (630, 305), 20)

            elif 2 and 5 and 8 in circleList:
                pygame.draw.line(wn, (208, 240, 192), (10, 305), (630, 305), 20)
            elif 3 and 5 and 7 in circleList:
                pygame.draw.line(wn, (208,240,192), (10, 305), (630, 305), 20)
            elif 3 and 6 and 9 in circleList:
                pygame.draw.line(wn, (208,240,192), (10, 305), (630, 305), 20)
            elif 4 and 5 and 6 in circleList:
                pygame.draw.line(wn, (208,240,192), (10, 305), (630, 305), 20)
            elif 7 and 8 and 9 in circleList:
                pygame.draw.line(wn, (208,240,192), (10, 305), (630, 305), 20)




    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I know the line printing in the wrong direction I intend to fix it after I figure this out could really use someone's help

Comment: `if 1 and 2 and 3 in circleList:` and the like does not work the way you intend: it checks whether the value `1` is true (it is, as it is not 0), whether `2` is true (it is as well), and if `3 in circleList` is true. You probably want `if 1 in circleList and 2 in circleList and 3 in circleList`; similar for the following `elif` lines.

Comment: 0 0 is correct... That is the reason that your code isn't working. For future reference if you want to avoid the large quantity of downvotes you have acquired and get better answers, you should provide the minimum amount of code which will produce the error you are receiving. It makes it much easier for people to answer your questions

Answer (score 1):

In the lines that are all `if 1 and 2 and 3 in circleList:`, you should try and replace it to `if 1 in circleList and 2 in circleList and 3 in circleList:`, since saying `1 and 2 and 3 in circleList` actually just means - if 1 is a value and if two is a value and if 3 is in circleList, then continue. I hope you understand that what the correction means is that you need to check if 1 is in circleList, if 2 is in circleList, and if 3 is in it. It also applies to the `elifs` after it.